# draggable won't work untill another element is dragged

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

im having troubles with a draggable div, im trying to build an ui where u can drag and drop from a palette into a workspace.

basically what i do is that i have a hidden div with the elements that each palette item represent, and when i click on the palette item, i clone the corresponding hidden item and append it to the editor div (so can be moved all arround) and then triger the mouse event (so you dont have to click again to move it).

after that the cloned item (thats already storaged in a global variable) gets removed from the document on drop, if the element was dropped over the workspace, then i append the element to the workspace (so can only be moved inside the workspace), but wont move at all untill u drop a new element into the workspace.

this is my code:.

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    #editor{
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightcyan;
    }
    #elements{
        display: none;
    }
    #palette{
        height: 100%;
        width: 125px;
        float: left;
        background: lightgrey;
    }
    .editor-pane{
        height: 10%;
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        background: lightyellow;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .editor-palette-item{
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
    .palette-item-container{
        cursor: pointer;
        cursor: hand;
        padding: 16px;
    }

    #workspace{
        height: 100%;
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        background: white;
    }
    body{
        width: 97%;
        height: 750px;
    }
</style>
```

**html:**

```
<div id="editor" style="border: solid; ">
    <div id="palette">
        <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element1">
            <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
            Element1
        </div>
        <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element2">
            <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
            Element2
        </div>
        <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element3">
            <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
            Element3
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="workspace">
        
    </div>
    
    <div id="elements">
        <div id="element1" class="editor-pane"></div>
        <div id="element2" class="editor-pane"></div>
        <div id="element3" class="editor-pane"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    var ElementCopy = null;
    
    $('#palette .palette-item-container').mousedown(function(evt) {
        ElementCopy = $('#' + $(this).attr("elementId")).clone().removeAttr('id');
        $('#editor').append(ElementCopy);
        ElementCopy.draggable({
            containment: "parent"
        });
        ElementCopy.css("left", evt.clientX - 20 + "px");
        ElementCopy.css("top", evt.clientY - 20 + "px");
        ElementCopy.trigger(evt);
        // console.log(evt);

        ElementCopy.mouseup(function(e){
            ElementCopy.draggable( "destroy" );
            ElementCopy.remove();
        });
    }); 
    
    $('#workspace').droppable({
        drop: function(evt) {
            if (ElementCopy){
                $('#workspace').append(ElementCopy);
                $('#workspace .editor-pane').resizable({
                    containment: "parent"
                })
                .draggable({
                    containment: "parent"
                });
                // $('#workspace .editor-pane').addClass('ui-draggable-handle');
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            #editor{
                position: relative;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: lightcyan;
            }
            #elements{
                display: none;
            }
            #palette{
                height: 100%;
                width: 125px;
                float: left;
                background: lightgrey;
            }
            .editor-pane{
                height: 10%;
                width: 20%;
                float: left;
                background: lightyellow;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .editor-palette-item{
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
            }
            .palette-item-container{
                cursor: pointer;
                cursor: hand;
                padding: 16px;
            }

            #workspace{
                height: 100%;
                width: 70%;
                float: left;
                background: white;
            }
            body{
                width: 97%;
                height: 750px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor" style="border: solid; ">
            <div id="palette">
                <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element1">
                    <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
                    Element1
                </div>
                <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element2">
                    <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
                    Element2
                </div>
                <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element3">
                    <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
                    Element3
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div id="workspace">
                <!-- <div id="element2" class="editor-pane"></div> -->
            </div>
            
            <div id="elements">
                <div id="element1" class="editor-pane">element1 data</div>
                <div id="element2" class="editor-pane">element2 data</div>
                <div id="element3" class="editor-pane">element3 data</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var ElementCopy = null;
            /*  $("#element2").resizable({
                    containment: "parent"
                }).draggable({
                    containment: "parent"
            }); */
            $('#palette .palette-item-container').mousedown(function(evt) {
                // console.log($(this).attr("elementId"));
                ElementCopy = $('#' + $(this).attr("elementId")).clone().removeAttr('id');
                $('#editor').append(ElementCopy);
                ElementCopy.draggable({
                    containment: "parent"
                });
                ElementCopy.css("left", evt.clientX - 20 + "px");
                ElementCopy.css("top", evt.clientY - 20 + "px");
                ElementCopy.trigger(evt);
                // console.log(evt);

                ElementCopy.mouseup(function(e){
                    ElementCopy.draggable( "destroy" );
                    ElementCopy.remove();
                });
            }); 
            
            $('#workspace').droppable({
                drop: function(evt) {
                    if (ElementCopy){
                        $('#workspace').append(ElementCopy);
                        $('#workspace .editor-pane').resizable({
                            containment: "parent"
                        })
                        .draggable({
                            containment: "parent"
                        });
                        // $('#workspace .editor-pane').addClass('ui-draggable-handle');
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect the issue is within the logic of the mousedown event. I think this is bubbling up in a way that draggable cannot be initialized and capture the event. Hence, the draggable is not initialized unti lthe second mousedown event. Is there a reason you are not just initializing those elements as draggable up front?

Comment: i need to be able to build a customable workspace and then save it as a template to visualize in a different page, so this would be like the page builder of some sort, so, as in the example, i need to be able to drag the elements around, or maybe not even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#palette > .palette-item-container').draggable({
    containment: $("#editor"),
    helper: "clone",
    cursorAt: {
      left: -5,
      top: -5
    }
  });

  $('#workspace').droppable({
    drop: function(evt, ui) {
      var elemCopy = ui.helper.clone().removeClass("ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging");
      elemCopy.attr("id", null).appendTo(this);
      elemCopy.draggable({
        containment: "parent"
      }).resizable({
        containment: "parent"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#editor {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightcyan;
}

#elements {
  display: none;
}

#palette {
  height: 100%;
  width: 125px;
  float: left;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.editor-pane {
  height: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  background: lightyellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.editor-palette-item {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}

.palette-item-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  padding: 16px;
}

#workspace {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background: white;
}

body {
  width: 97%;
  height: 750px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="editor" style="border: solid; ">
  <div id="palette">
    <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element1">
      <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
      Element1
    </div>
    <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element2">
      <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
      Element2
    </div>
    <div class="palette-item-container" elementId="element3">
      <div class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
      Element3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="workspace">
    <!-- <div id="element2" class="editor-pane"></div> -->
  </div>

  <div id="elements">
    <div id="element1" class="editor-pane">element1 data</div>
    <div id="element2" class="editor-pane">element2 data</div>
    <div id="element3" class="editor-pane">element3 data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you clone an element, it does not clone the event callbacks by default. So a Draggable Helper that is clones will not be draggable. Yet it may have some of the classes left over. Usually best to address all this is Droppable.

Comment: the thing is that in this code, you clone the element from the palette itself, but i cant do that, coz inside each element, there will be data, data thats too big or too messy to fit on the palette, so the palette elements are representations of the elements, not the elements themsleves. Also, for some reason this code duplicates the elements after second drag :(